# Adding assets image with angular 8 and webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to quickly add some images to a project that uses webpack. I manage the Angular App but I never used webpack. I just added a src/assets/images folder with a logo.png file into the project. Then, I needed it:

```
<img src="../../assets/images/logo.png">
```

But I can not use it because when I run npm start, I get this error:

> ERROR in ./src/assets/images/logo_app.png 1:0
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
>   configured to process this file. See
>   https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Can you please, help me how can I quickly add this image? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use:

```html
<img src="assets/images/logo.png">
```

This will work considering in your `angular.json` file, the `assets` folder is included in the `assets` array of the build options (it's there by default)

```
//...
"architect": {
  "build": {
  //..
    "options": {
    //..
      "assets": [
        "path/to/assets/folder",
      ],
//..
}
```

Comment: what if I am doing with angular webpack??